# How to tell when selection is made in Wordpress 3.5 Media Editor

Tags: media, wordpress-3.5

I am trying to bind to the 'selection:single' trigger that occurs when an item is selected in the new Wordpress media uploader.

I can see that at line 895 of media models.js there is this trigger

```
this._single.trigger( 'selection:single', this._single, this );
```

But I cannot work out what I should bind the listener to so that I can get the data that is sent when that happens.

I am just using the default deployment of the media editor created in the front end by wp.media.editor.open()...

Have been searching for a day now and cannot find a solution :(